# What is the algorithm for the 3D rigid superimposition?

Tags: vector-spaces, geometry

Someone here know how to perform a rigid superimposition in a 3D cartesian plane for two or more objects?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Could you please add some details to your question, including: 1. What is an "object", and  (if you're talking about some type of computer programming) how an object is represented; 2. What you mean by "rigid superimposition" (rigid Euclidean motion? Translation...?); 3. Any other appropriate details, possibly including what you're trying to accomplish, and why? Thank you. :)

Comment: Hm, looks like a problem in Virtual Reality. Might be an overlay over a real, physical rigid body object. E.g. turn a baseball bat into a sword.

Comment: I dunno but I bet it has something to do with the quaternions.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm developing a python module that analysis the 3D variation of RNA molecules. However, the module requires an external software to perform the rigid superimposition. I just want to avoid that external software in order to make easy the installation for the user. A better starting point is the RMSD article in Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation_of_atomic_positions).

Comment: I was asking for details mainly so knowledgeable future passersby might be able to help. (At first I wasn't even sure what field your question lay in.) The link you provided, however, eventually leads to the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) for calculating the optimal rotation after translating your paired data sets so their centroids are at the origin. Aside from possibly being computation-intensive, the theory looks straightforward; does that help?